# Spivak Calculus 24-12

Tags: real-analysis

This is question 24-12 of Spivak's Calculus:
[image]

Can someone explain the part in yellow to me?  I don't see how it follows.

Answer (score 0):

We can always find a sequence,$\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\rightarrow 0$, such that $\sin(1/x_{n})=0$ for every $n$. e.g., take $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$.

Comment: And the second part starting: "It also shows..."

Comment: Take a sequence of negative elements converging to $0$. This satisfies part $(b)$ of the problem.